# how to dynamically parse Json data using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a requirement to determine a generic standard approach to read the JSON data ( should be able to read any JSON structure) and display in reactjs page. 
I know that if we know JSON structure, we can traverse through it and display the data in the page accordingly. But here JSON structure
should be dynamically determined via code and we should not code specifically for each JSON structure.

For example, I have given Sample1.json and Sample2.json files below. My program should be able to parse Sample1.json if I use it and display
them on the page. If I use Sample2.json, still it should be able to parse them and display the data dynamically. We should not have
code specifically like archive_header.tracking_id or stock_ledger_sales_key.version_number...etc.

Can someone please let me know how to handle this scenario?

**Sample1.json**

```js
{
  "archive_header": {
    "tracking_id": "914553536-FRM01-20163609140455-000000001",
    "archived_timestamp": "2018-05-08T09:14:04.055-05:00"
  },
  "journal_record_key": {
    "location_number": "389234",
    "dept_number": "28822"
  },
  "journal_record_detail": {
    "financial_from_item_number": "771",
    "financial_to_item_number": "771"
  }
}
```

---

**Sample2.json**

```js
{
  "stock_ledger_sales_key": {
    "version_number": "12",
    "account_month_number": "01",
    "account_year_number": "2016"
  },
  "stock_ledger_sales_detail": {
    "mature_increase_mtd_percentage": "1.2",
    "mature_increase_stdt_percentage": "2.3",
    "mature_increase_ytd_percentage": "2"
  }
}
```

Comment: what information do you want to display from the json?

Comment: i want to display all the information from json. For example if i use sample1.json, I would display tracking_id = 914553536-FRM01-20163609140455-000000001, location_number = 389234, dept_number: 28822, financial_from_item_number =  771 , financial_to_item_number  = 771

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the information as you said, we can do something like this:

```js
const jsonDOM = json => {
  return Object.keys(json).map(key => {
    return Object.keys(json[key]).map(child => {
      return (<div>
        <p>{child}</p>
        <p>{json[key][child]}</p>
        </div>
      );
    });
  });
};

return (<div>
  <h2>JSON 1</h2>
  {jsonDOM(json1)} 
  <h2>JSON 2</h2>
  {jsonDOM(json2)} 
  </div>
);
```

Here is the live [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGobev?editors=0010)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thinker, Really Awesome!!! This really works well. Thank you for the quick response...

Comment: Glad I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over the keys recursively:

```
function recursively_iterate(object, parent_name="") {
  output = ""
  for (key in Object.keys(object)) {
    if (typeof object[key] == "object") {
      output = output + recursively_iterate(object[key], key)
    }
    output = output + parent_name + "." + key + ": " + object[key] + "\n"
  }
  return output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify` and `<pre>` tag to output any json you like.

```js
const sample1 = {
  archive_header: {
    tracking_id: "914553536-FRM01-20163609140455-000000001",
    archived_timestamp: "2018-05-08T09:14:04.055-05:00"
  },
  journal_record_key: {
    location_number: "389234",
    dept_number: "28822"
  },
  journal_record_detail: {
    financial_from_item_number: "771",
    financial_to_item_number: "771"
  }
};

const sample2 = {
  stock_ledger_sales_key: {
    version_number: "12",
    account_month_number: "01",
    account_year_number: "2016"
  },
  stock_ledger_sales_detail: {
    mature_increase_mtd_percentage: "1.2",
    mature_increase_stdt_percentage: "2.3",
    mature_increase_ytd_percentage: "2"
  }
};

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>sample1</h3>
        <pre>
          <code>{JSON.stringify(sample1, null, 2)}</code>
        </pre>
        <h3>sample2</h3>
        <pre>
          <code>{JSON.stringify(sample2, null, 2)}</code>
        </pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```